# Abrir el mismo archivo desde varias (o todas) las URLs

Tags: .htaccess, url

He visto que muchas páginas abren el mismo archivo (por ejemplo `/home/index.php`) ya sea que pongas `ejemplo.com/articulo1` o `ejemplo.com/articulo2`.

Mi objetivo con esto es reemplazar los `home/&var=ejemplo` por `home/ejemplo` y desde el mismo archivo leer la URL y mostrar el contenido que necesito.

Lo que quiero es saber cómo se puede hacer esto, me imagino que desde `htacces`, pero he buscado y de ninguna forma encuentro nada.

> Por ejemplo, WordPress lo usa, y como ya sabemos no crea un archivo
>   para cada artículo, sino que lee el enlace y lo muestra desde el mismo
>   archivo mediante la base de datos.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Es muy sencillo de hacer, primero crea un archivo `.htaccess` con lo siguiente:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Redirigimos todas las peticiones a excepcion de los archivos de imagenes, css y js.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.css|\.js)$
RewriteRule (.*)  index.php [QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Con esto todas las solicitudes que se hagan a tu dominio serán redireccionadas al archivo index.php. Ahora ya queda que obtengas las variables que necesites por `$_GET` y `$_POST`. Te recomiendo una librería llamada [Phroute](https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute) para facilitarte esta tarea.

Saludos!